# MDM (Mobile Device management) in J2ME

Tags: java-me, mdm

I want to implement MDM in J2ME. Whenever I update App, I am able to upload New App in Mobile, I can upload it successfully. But My Problem is that, I want to replace existing App and then want to upload new App. As of now I can add App on Device with Different name (Same App Name is not working) but cant replace App.

Here is my code for MDM:

```
    public void getUpdateApp() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {

                DataHelper dh = new DataHelper(parent);
                dh.openRecord();
                String response_rms = dh.getupdateAppinfo_str();
                System.out.println("response from RMS of Update App  info in appupdate---" + response_rms);

                System.out.println("Sending update App Call.");
                HttpConn httpConnect = new HttpConn(parent);

                UserInfo userInfo = getUserInfo();


                String data = "AppCode=" + AppData.appCode+ "&CurrentVersion=" + AppData.currentversion
                        + "&TerminalNumber=" + userInfo.getTerminalNumber()
                        + "&apifunction=" + "GetAppUpdate";

                httpConnect.sendPostRequest_appupdate(AppData.AppUpdateURL, data, new ConnectionListener() {

                    public void onRequestFailure(Object title, Object message) {
                        System.out.println("==>GetUpdateApp Failure\nTitle:"
                                + (String) title
                                + "\n Failure Message" + (String) message);
                        showMessageDialog((String) title, (String) message, new SettingsForm("Settings", parent), 2000);
                    }

                    public void onRequestSuccess(Object httpResponse) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("==>On Success--of Update App");
                            String response = (String) httpResponse;
                            System.out.println("==>Login Form--Update App \nResponse:" + response);
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            int responseCode = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("ResponseCode"));
                            switch (responseCode) {
                                case 000: {
                                    String latestbuild = jsonObject.getString("LatestBuild");
                                    String latestversion = jsonObject.getString("LatestVersion");
                                    String downloadURL = jsonObject.getString("DownloadURL");

                                    if (latestversion != null) {
                                        if (!latestversion.equals(AppData.currentversion) || !latestbuild.equals(AppData.currentBuild)) {

                                            if (Integer.parseInt(latestbuild) > Integer.parseInt(AppData.currentBuild)) {
                                                System.out.println("Download URL--" + downloadURL);

                                             //   parent.platformRequest(downloadURL);
                                                    System.out.println("platform request boolean variable returns---"+ parent.platformRequest(downloadURL));
                                                   parent.platformRequest(downloadURL);

                                                    parent.destroyApp(true);




                                            } else {

                                                System.out.println("Incomapatible types");
                                                showMessageDialog("Alert", "No new updates available", new SettingsForm("Settings", parent),2000);
                                            }

                                        } else {
                                            System.out.println("App Version Number is same,No New Build Available");
                                            showMessageDialog("Alert", "Application is already upto date", new SettingsForm("Settings", parent),2000);
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        System.out.println("App version not available on server");
                                        showMessageDialog("Alert", "No new updates available", new SettingsForm("Settings", parent),2000);
                                    }
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                            showdisplayExceptionDialog(ex, new SettingsForm("Settings", parent));

                        } catch (ConnectionNotFoundException ex) {
                            showdisplayExceptionDialog(ex, new SettingsForm("Settings", parent));
                        }

                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                showdisplayExceptionDialog(e, new SettingsForm("Settings", parent));
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

If any 1 has  any idea regarding Replacing App in J2ME then please Help me. Thanks a lot in Advance.